# Collisions in list removals when there shouldn't be

Tags: python, list

So I have a piece of code that puts two words into a database from a big list, and then removes both of those words from the list so neither is used again. When the list gets almost to its end, it's passed to an unrelated function.

```
def db_add(words):
    for i in words:
        choice = randint(2, 9)
        if len(words) < choice:
            finish(words)
        else:
            cursor.execute(
                'INSERT INTO swaps (word1, word2) VALUES (%s, %s);', (i, words[choice])
            )
            conn.commit()
            words.remove(words[choice])
            words.remove(i)
```

Now, this fails—usually early—due to being unable to remove `i` from the list. Using a few print statements I found this was happening when `i` and `words[choice]` somehow end up being the same words. But since choice is never 0, I don't see how `i` and `words[choice]` can ever be equal.

My only guess is that it's got something to do with manipulating lists during use in for statements, or it's a really stupid mistake I'm making, but I really have no idea.

Comment: Could part of the problem, at least, be that the `cursor.execute` argument should be `'INSERT INTO swaps (word1, word2) VALUES (%s, %s);' % (i, words[choice]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are modifying the list as you are iterating over it.  This inevitably leads to problems.  If you need to remove elements from the list, it is recommended that you make a copy of the list, remove words from the copy, and then return the copy.

```
def db_add(words):
    words_copy = words.copy()
    for i in words:
        choice = randint(2, 9)
        if len(words) < choice:
            finish(words)
        else:
            cursor.execute(
                'INSERT INTO swaps (word1, word2) VALUES (%s, %s);', (i, words[choice])
            )
            conn.commit()
            words_copy.remove(words_copy[choice])
            words_copy.remove(i)
```

Comment: thank you, seems like it will work for the most part. But any idea how to keep feeding that copied list back in to the loop? I can't keep using the starting word list because I can't have two of the same word in the DB. I'm pretty sure recursion will reach a max limit on > 300,000 word list.